# How can I write sec in Write format in Fortran?

Tags: fortran

I want to write the time in a txt file but I have a problem. The problem is if the Sec is **14.999 or sec is 10^-6** so that it will be wrong. How can I write this conditions? where am I doing wrong? The result is for second case is **0.000** but I need **00.000**.

```
  The first one result is   : 14.999
  The second one result is  :  0.  0
  First condition Milisec = 999
  Second condition  Milisec = 0
  -------------------------
  Result should be if sec is 14.999   : 14.999
  Result should be if sec is 10^-6   :  00.000
  ---------------------Code --------------------
  program test

  Real :: Sec,Sec2
  integer  :: milisec, Milisec2
   Sec=14.999
  milisec = 999
  Sec2=0
  milisec2 = 0


  Write(*, 400)  int(sec), '.', milisec 
  Write(*, 400)  int(Sec2), '.', milisec2 
  400 Format (I2,A1,I3.3)
  end program test
```

Comment: Please add a MWE and not just a code snippet. Also strange to start your write statement with a `,` whilst the format has `A`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please, take the [tour] and learn [ask]. Then, present us a clear description of what are you trying to do, what you got wrong and what you expected to get, along with a [mcve]>

Comment: @albert I edited the code and test code for that

Comment: Try changing `(I3,A1,I3)` to `(I3,A1,I3.3)`.  I don't have time right now for a full explanation, but it's been covered many times here, and any good documentation will explain.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark the result is 0.000 but should be 00.000

Comment: In the previous version you used for e.g. the month field 'I0.2' so now you could use 'I0.3' or like High Performance Mark says 'I3.3'. Note also seconds should be 2 positions.

Comment: What is the remaining problem? did you use 'I2.2' and 'I3.3' as format parts ?

Comment: Thanks a lot :) it is working :) I like this community :)